# ASP.NET Database searching using dropdown list with paging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created ASP.NET MVC Web App. I've got a question about searching in database using dropdown list with paging. I used this tutorial:
[tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), so my code is the same.
And I also created dropdown list in View:

`Search: @Html.DropDownList("type", ViewBag.currentType as string)`

I tried to do it the same way as it was done in tutorial, but searching works fine only until I go to the second page. When page is changed, searching is reset to default, first type. 
Creating my list:

```
        var typeList = new List<string>();
        var type = from o in db.Typies
                  orderby o.Name
                  select o.Name;
        typeList.Add("all");
        typeList.AddRange(type.Distinct());
        ViewBag.type = new SelectList(typeList);
```

I can easily get selected item, but have no idea how to make it selected after page is changed. So, my question: How can I restore/set selected dropdownlist item when page is changed?

Comment: You'll need to pass the currently selected item to the next page. You are also using the wrong [DropDownList overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29). This [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper) has examples.

Comment: Thanks :) well, that's not exactly what I wanted, but It is very informative tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I figured out I can manage selected dropdownlist value between pages by saving it as a Session parameter and check that parameter on every page :)